# How do I test if a variable does not equal either of two values?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, equals, boolean-logic

I want to write an if/else statement that tests if the value of a text input does NOT equal either one of two different values. Like this (excuse my pseudo-English code):

```
var test = $("#test").val();
if (test does not equal A or B){
    do stuff;
}
else {
    do other stuff;
}
```

How do I write the condition for the if statement on line 2?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Think of `!` (negation operator) as "not", `||` (boolean-or operator) as "or" and `&&` (boolean-and operator) as "and". See [Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference#Operators) and [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Thus:

```
if(!(a || b)) {
  // means neither a nor b
}
```

However, using [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), it could be written as:

```
if(!a && !b) {
  // is not a and is not b
}
```

`a` and `b` above can be any expression (such as `test == 'B'` or whatever it needs to be).

Once again, if `test == 'A'` and `test == 'B'`, are the expressions, note the expansion of the 1st form:

```
// if(!(a || b)) 
if(!((test == 'A') || (test == 'B')))
// or more simply, removing the inner parenthesis as
// || and && have a lower precedence than comparison and negation operators
if(!(test == 'A' || test == 'B'))
// and using DeMorgan's, we can turn this into
// this is the same as substituting into if(!a && !b)
if(!(test == 'A') && !(test == 'B'))
// and this can be simplified as !(x == y) is the same as (x != y)
if(test != 'A' && test != 'B')
```

Comment: Is there any shorter way to do it like this (pseudo-code): `if(test === ('A' || 'B'))` (I removed the `!` for logical simplicity, I'm more curious about the concept)

Comment: A short version like `if(x == 2|3)` would be nice to have.

Answer (score 81):

ECMA2016 answer, especially good when checking against multiple values:

```
if (!["A","B", ...].includes(test)) {}
```

Comment: This is the JavaScript way to answer the question.  He wasn't asking about how to use && or || but he was looking for a shortcut that allows; test == ( 'string1' || string2) which would be equivalent to (test == 'string2') || (test == string1)

Comment: Here's an old but relevant reference; https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/03/14/better-ways-of-comparing-a-javascript-string-to-multiple-values/

Comment: This is niiiice, thanks. Never thought of .includes( ) this way. Kinda feels like using it "reverse", because of how I fundamentally thought about a relation between variables and their values.
Equality means inclusion in both directions, wonderful :)

Answer (score 12):

In general it would be something like this:

```
if(test != "A" && test != "B")
```

You should probably read up on JavaScript logical operators.

Answer (score 2):

I do that using jQuery

```
if ( 0 > $.inArray( test, [a,b] ) ) { ... }
```

Comment: If anyone continues to get undesired results with this then you can also check that the typeof of the test and a, b must match too if you need to get true as result.

Comment: Not a fan of this at all, it seems much easier to test `(test != 'A' && test != 'B')` and it reads nicer

Answer (score 2):

For a larger number of values that is checked against often, it may be more efficient to check if the value does not exist in a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
const values = new Set(["a", "b"]);
if(!values.has(someValue)){
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = $("#test").val();
if (test != 'A' && test != 'B'){
    do stuff;
}
else {
    do other stuff;
}
```

Comment: You mean `test != A && test != B`, else it will always execute (unless test == A == B)

Comment: @Neal: the OP wants the code executed if the value `does NOT equal either one of two` -> **either** one!

Comment: @Neal: The `if()` in this answer will always be `true` because `test` will always *not* equal one or the other.

Comment: @patrick: that's incorrect, I already put a counterexample in my first comment on this answer...

Comment: @Jurgen: that was pseudocode, read his question to see what he wants.

Comment: @Konerak: Read my comment again. I was agreeing with you. I updated the wording to make it more clear. In the original answer with `||`, the `if()` would *always* evaluate to `true` because `test` will always *not* be either `'A'` or `'B'`.

Comment: ...notice that `'A'` and `'B'` are strings, so they're never equal.

Comment: Heh, ok, in the answer they are literals, in the OP's question they are strings.

Answer (score 0):

You used the word "or" in your pseudo code, but based on your first sentence, I think you mean and. There was some confusion about this because that is not how people usually speak.

You want:

```
var test = $("#test").val();
if (test !== 'A' && test !== 'B'){
    do stuff;
}
else {
    do other stuff;
}
```