# Why SSI condition != || != doesn't work?

Tags: include, ssi, server-side-includes

I can't get working this conditional expression

```
<!--#if expr="$DOCUMENT_NAME!=index.html || $DOCUMENT_NAME!=links.html" -->
```

while this one without `!` before `=` works perfect

```
<!--#if expr="$DOCUMENT_NAME=index.html || $DOCUMENT_NAME=links.html" -->
```

What's the problem? I get no error simply `!=` doesn't work though `||` with other condition but works for single condition.

Comment: Not working - does that mean syntax error or giving you unexpected results?

Comment: I've got no errors. Single conditional expression works `<!--#if expr="$DOCUMENT_NAME!=index.html" -->`. But if I add `||` and other conditions then nothing is working and no SII error as well.

Comment: The same condition though `||` but `=` instead of `!=` works. What a weird?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `=` and `!=` are hardly the same operator. Note that, by [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) (which I also [explained in this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115801/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-does-not-equal-either-of-two-values/6115869#6115869)),

```
a != b || c != d
```

is equivalent to

```
a = b && c = d
```

which is **never true** for `x = a && x = b` where `a != b`.

Changing the binary operator *requires* changing the conditionals as well to be equivalent.

Thus, by the above logic,

```
$DOCUMENT_NAME!=index.html || $DOCUMENT_NAME!=links.html
```

is equivalent to

```
$DOCUMENT_NAME=index.html && $DOCUMENT_NAME=links.html
```

which *cannot* be true as $DOCUMENT_NAME can be "index.html" *or* "links.html" but *not both*.

However, the 2nd snippet,

```
$DOCUMENT_NAME=index.html || $DOCUMENT_NAME=links.html
```

"works" because there is not the logical never-true fallacy mentioned above. It will be true when $DOCUMENT_NAME is *either* "index.html" or "links.html".

---

Some languages/values will violate the above equivalency .. but that is another topic.

Comment: Thank you for response. However I'm still a bit confused. How then implement this idea other way? Basically I have a script in header and need to show that on all pages but not on index.html, links.html and also a few other pages I want to ignore to be show the script.

Comment: Then write what you mean: `a != b && a != c` which is equivalent to `!(a == b || a == c)`: "It is *not* the case that a is equal to b *or* c."

Comment: OK I understand that now. But how I can do in SSI condition to exclude showing script on particular pages?

Comment: `$DOCUMENT_NAME!=index.html && $DOCUMENT_NAME!=links.html` or `!($DOCUMENT_NAME=index.html || $DOCUMENT_NAME=links.html)` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you! `!($DOCUMENT_NAME=index.html || $DOCUMENT_NAME=links.html)` That's what I was looking for.