# While or and not equal to not working?

Tags: c#, string, loops, while-loop

Im quite new to C# and am trying to write a super simple loop

```
        while ((var_app_choice != "Exit") || (var_app_choice != "Test"))
        {
            //stuff
        }
```

I have a console application where an end user will input a value

If this value is not equal (!=) to Exit OR Test then it should loop.

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Here is [my answer from a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12169950/166390). It deals with a different implementation (IE conditionals, not C#), but the logic/reasoning is the same ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to come out of the loop, when the User enters `Exit` or `Test` then you need the `&&` operator not `||`

```
while ((var_app_choice != "Exit") && (var_app_choice != "Test"))
    {
        var_app_choice = Console.ReadLine();
        //stuff
    }
```

Comment: I think I need more sleep! This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: According to De Morgan's law this can also be written: `while (!(var_app_choice == "Exit" || var_app_choice == "Test")) { ... }`. The "not" operator `!` has been "pulled out", and "and" changed to "or".

Comment: I agree your version is most clear. I just wanted to give another formal expression of _"the choice is not Exit **or** Test"_.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want and not or...

If the value of `var_app_choice` is "Test", then the first condition is true and the loop will execute.  Similarly, if it's "Exit", then the second condition is true.  In other words, you have an infinite loop...

Answer (score 1):

lets say x=1;

few things here ,

- lets say true means ON and false means OFF.and we have Gate, when Gate is ON loop and 'if statement' will execute otherwise it won't.

  ```
                                                                Output
  ```

> ```
>  -When you use OR :    x!=1 || x!=2     :     OFF, ON      =   ON
>
>  -When you use AND :   x!=1 && x!=2     :     OFF, ON      =   OFF
> ```

Now  if you don't know De Morgan's law or don't know about AND/OR gates in electronics. let me tell you
difference between an AND and an OR is that an AND gate gives output true, if all its inputs are true, whereas an OR gate gives output true if any one of its inputs is true
Thats is Why the result of  x!=1 || x!=2  is True. and loop keps looping if statement results in true. so as long as while(true) : loop keeps looping. and while(false) it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

Friend,

Consider I am having a data list as

List dataList = new List() { "Apple", "Microsoft", "exit", "Oracle", "Android" };

int i = 0;
                while (dataList[i] != "exit" || dataList[i] != "test")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dataList[i]);
                    i++;
                }

You would expect that the ouput should be only Apple and Microsoft. When it encounters "exit" in index 2 it should stop.

What really happens(consider it is verifying "exit") is the first condition fails, which means NotEqualTo Operator works fine. The problem is your OR operator. Since "exit" not equals "test", the condition passed and it further enters into the loop.

Your data must not be equal to "exit" and also not equal to "test".

Think you got the problem. For your information, While(condn){} here you can mention any condition that outputs a boolean(true or false).

Thanks and Correct me if I am wrong.