# How to write a basic check for an invalid email address

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to validate an email address in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026842/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-php)

Below I have a piece of code where it checks for a valid email address:

```
if ( (strlen($getemail) >= 7) && (strstr($getemail, "@")) && (strstr($getemail, ".")) ){
```

But what my question is that what is the opposite of the code above so that I can check if the email typed in does not contain all of the features above?

Comment: Could this be like .. a duplicate?

Comment: In any case, `!allOfFeatures` is the "opposite" of `allOfFeatures`; the boolean-logic negation can be applied through `&&` (and `||`) operators by De Morgan's, here are two answers I wrote on it in general: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169639/why-ssi-condition-doesnt-work?lq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115801/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-does-not-equal-either-of-two-values/6115869#6115869 (and they have sufficient detail for the "logic" of such inversions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!( (strlen($getemail) >= 7) && (strstr($getemail, "@")) && (strstr($getemail, ".")) )){
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP already has a function that can do this for you. It's called [filter_var](http://php.net/filter-var) and what you're looking for is the [validation filter](http://php.net/filter.filters.validate) for `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`.

**Example:**

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // It's a valid email address
} else {
    // It's not a valid email address
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that what are you trying to do can be achieved be RegEx.

```
var_dump(preg_match('#^(\w+){7,}@(\w+)\.([a-z]){2,4}$#i', 'example@example.com')); # 1 (true)
var_dump(preg_match('#^(\w+){7,}@(\w+)\.([a-z]){2,4}$#i', 'foo@example.com')); # 0 (false)
```

If one of the conditions is not met (make sure address is alphanumeric, 7 chars minimum, followed by @, etc.), entire expression would result in false value.

Example:

```
if(preg_match('#^(\w+){7,}@(\w+)\.([a-z]){2,4}$#i', $email))
{
// do stuff
}
```

**Do not validate email like that**, use inbuilt `filter_var` function. There is no real way of validating if email is "real", main problem are domains, TLDs that is.