# Is is the Boolean result of !empty($variable) and count($variable) always equal in PHP?

Tags: php, count, php-7, php-5.6, is-empty

I need to replace the occurrences of 
count($variable) with !empty($variable) in IF statements
so instead of

```
if(count($variable)){

}
```

I would like to use

```
if(!empty($variable)){

}
```

Is it safe to replace it always while ensuring that the result is always the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I test if a variable does not equal either of two values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115801/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-does-not-equal-either-of-two-values)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115801/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-does-not-equal-either-of-two-values

Comment: @Labradorcode OP asks whether `if(count($variable))` and `if(!empty($variable))` are interchangeable. I don't really see how the proposed duplicate answers that. (Not to mention that it's a different language.)

Comment: `count('')` throws an error. Those are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

[Test it](https://3v4l.org/SdPPI):

```
foreach (['', null, 0, 0.0, '0', false, [], new stdClass, 'foo', 1, true, ['bar' => 'baz']] as $val) {
    var_dump($val, count($val), !empty($val));
    echo '-------------', PHP_EOL;
}
```

It differs for these cases:

```
string(0) ""
int(1)
bool(false)
-------------
int(0)
int(1)
bool(false)
-------------
float(0)
int(1)
bool(false)
-------------
string(1) "0"
int(1)
bool(false)
-------------
bool(false)
int(1)
bool(false)
```

Additionally, `count` will trigger an error for undefined variables. On PHP 7.2+, `count` also triggers an error for any non-`Countable` value (which is basically everything except `array` or classes that `implement Countable`).

So, *if* you can guarantee that your variable will always be an array, there's no difference. If your variable can be anything other than an array, including undefined, then you'll see anywhere between different results and errors triggered.

If you expect your variable to exist and to be an array/`Countable`, you should prefer `count` or just `if ($variable)` (since an empty array is *falsy* too) to get proper error messages if your value violates your expectations.

Comment: Worth mentioning that counting elements in an array to get boolean value is an overkill. An array can be used in boolean context without counting the elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to replace IF your current count() uses do not rely on non standard cases, such as:
count(false) (this will return 1)

If you are just counting arrays you should be good to go.