# This condition will always return 'true' since the types have no overlap

Tags: javascript, typescript

`if (this.program.segment !== Segment.Y || this.program.segment !== Segment.C) return text`

There are 5 different segments and I want to check for 2 specifically, C and Y. If the segment is one of the other 3, I want to return the text. Otherwise, execute what comes after this statement.

Why is this simple OR check giving an error: This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'Segment.Y' and 'Segment.C' have no overlap. I looked at other examples on SO but I don't see how it would work here.

Comment: "x is not a fish or x is not a bike" is not the same thing as "x is not a fish and x is not a bike". The first one will always be true: if x is a fish, then it's not a bike, therefore true. If x is a bike, then it's not a fish, therefore true. If x is a zebra, then it's neither a fish or a bike, so still true.

Comment: In this case, you need AND, not OR. With OR, even when `this.program.segment` is one of `Segment.Y` or `Segment.C`, the other inequality check will return true (it can't be *both* `Segment.Y` *and* `Segment.C` at the same time), making the entire expression true. Hence your linter error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I test if a variable does not equal either of two values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115801/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-does-not-equal-either-of-two-values)

Comment: `if (![Segment.Y, Segment.C].includes(this.program.segment)) return text`

Answer (score 2):

Got it. Just need to change it to AND instead of OR. Thank you to everyone above!